# Why generate the same random numbers in for loop?

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, random

When I run this code, all x1 attributes are initialized with the same generated random number. for example, all set to 2!!!

```
@dataclass
class Position:
    x1: int = 0
    x2: int = 0

@dataclass
class Particle:
    position: Position
    pbest: Position 
    velocity: Position
    f : float = 0.0

def initialize():
    particles=np.full(20,Particle(Position(),Position(),Position()))
    
    for p in particles:
        p.position.x1=random.randint(-5,5)
```

Answer (score 1):

You created a *single* instance of `Particle`, then created an array with 20 references to that object. Every time you change `p.position.x1`, you are updating that single object, regardless of which reference to the object you start with.

Instead, do something like

```
particles = np.array(Particle(Position(x1=random.randint(-5, 5)), Position(), Position()) for _ in range(20))
```